How to implement Same font Family in react as per FIGMA font Family?
I want to add font family of 'FIGMA' in react but its not implemented...Baloo CHETTAN 2 this
` <Typography variant="h6" component="div" style={{ font-Weight: 'bold', margin-Top: '30px', margin-Left: '30px' }}>
        Monthly Budget
      </Typography>`

font family I want to implement in react

You wrote "Monthly Report" in english. How it can be shown in a non-english format with font "Baloo"? You need the text translated to th on-english first and then fonts with change to "Balloo Chetan 2". But setup translation first.
